# Parsing website by jsoup Java

Tags: java, parsing, web, jsoup

I need to check a value on https://new.ppy.sh/u/9889129 from div class profile-header-extra__rank-box (pp score). But it's returns nothig from there. How to do it?

```
public class mainClass
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String url = "https://new.ppy.sh/u/9889129";
        Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

        String ppValue = document.select(".profile-header-extra__rank-global").text();
        System.out.println("PP: "+ppValue);
        }
    }
```

Comment: When I visit that URL, I'm not seeing the div you're looking for, so JSoup probably isn't either.  I see a CSS file with that class but not a div.  Are you sure you're looking for the right class?

Comment: here is screen of what i see: https://pp.userapi.com/c639523/v639523899/1ab67/r7kTzbFhLNA.jpg

Comment: You have a typo in your code. You are looking for  class `profile-header-extra__rank-box` but in your code is `profile-header-extra__rank-global`